# Better Recognition Tips Using ABBYY Mobile SDK

Tags: iphone, ocr, cjk, abbyy

I've been working with ABBYY Mobile SDK for iPhone for sometime to recognize Chinese characters using the iPhone's camera. There are some characters that no matter how I tweak the image or DPI settings with the line `[fineManager setDefaultImageResolution:dpi];`, I cannot get the correct result and it's pretty damn frustrating.

Does anyone have tips as to how to increase ABBYY accuracy? Is ABBYY's Chinese library just not very extensive?

For example, this character just never gets recognized properly:
[image]

Thanks for any tips.